# How to use local NPM package TS typings for ambient module (Handlebars)?

Tags: typescript, handlebars.js, webpack-4

I'm trying to integrate `npm i handlebars` into my existing TS (v 3.4.5) project but consistently get `TS2307: Cannot find module 'handlebars'.`.

I'm using Handlebars in a few different modules spread out across various files.

As per this [merged feature](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/1487) the maintainers imported typings from DefinitelyTyped into the handlebars repo and they depreciated the [@types/handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/handlebars) package.

TS seems to be unable to locate the repo typings and shows the TS2307 error from above.

The only way I've been able to get a clean compile is to manually copy the .d.ts file from the repo into a self-made @types/handlebars folder.

At that point as long as I do one of:

- `import Handlebars from "handlebars";`
- `import * as Handlebars from "handlebars"`
- `import "handlebars"`

in just 1 of the files that use Handlebars I'm able to to generate an error free build.

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "./Scripts/app/**/*",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ]
}
```

Without manually copying the .d.ts file nothing seems to work.

So I've got two questions:

1. What's the correct way of getting Typescript to recognize this ambient module that doesn't require the manual copy/paste?
2. Why does TS only require the import statement in one of the modules that use Handlebars? Shouldn't it be required in all the modules that reference it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) for the TS documentation:

> Now we can ///  node.d.ts and then load the modules using import url = require("url"); or import * as URL from "url".

This seems to be the only way to reference an ambient module that doesn't exist in the @types directory. The import statement wasn't necessary to get it to compile.

For the record I also tried updating the tsconfig.json's include path to reference the .d.ts but it was ignored.